# How to access variable inside jquery promise

Tags: jquery, promise

I have a variable declared inside a function and the same function also contain code for an ajax call. Now I want to access that variable inside the `.done` ,`fail` & `always` function of this `promise`. But on consoling inside `done` it is logging `undefined`

```
// Rest of code
click:function(event){
    var getTrtCode = "someVar";
    var makeCall = $.ajax({
         url:"someUrl"
      })
     makeCall.done(function(response){
            console.log(" *******  "+getTrtCode);
                     })
        .always(function(){

                    })
            }
```

**EDIT**

I dont want to make `getTrtCode` a global variable

Comment: you need to use/declare a global variable and set the value depending on the need so you can access it anywhere and anyway you like

Comment: @guradio I just want to avoid the global variable which I already tried. I will update the question

Comment: You code should work as-is since they are all created in the same scope.

Comment: The `getTrtCode` is declared in a closure scope, so any function that is declared inside the click handler can access that variable... so your `done` callback should work as it is